# Can Eclipse convert if-else to switch for enums

Tags: eclipse

ReShaper can automatically recognize `if` states on enums and offer to convert them to `switch` statements (or back). (Of course, this can only happen if the `if` statements are solely testing the enums and nothing else.)

Can Eclipse do something like that and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse can convert switch statements to if-else but not the other way around. There is already a bug open to provide a "Convert 'if-else' to 'switch'" quick assist, see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=348179

Update: The bug has been fixed, Starting 4.3 Milestone 1 Eclipse will support converting if-else statements to switch statements.

Answer (score 8):

For sake of completeness, the option `Convert 'if-else' to 'switch'` is shown by having the cursor e.g. on the `if` and then pressing the quick-assist command (`Ctrl + 1`).